springboot integration apereo.cas
I protect a URL, http://localhost:8080/protected. When reading this URL, it will go to CAS LOGIN PAGE. After successful login, I can go to this URL, but when reading this URL, it will show that it cannot be read(HTTP CODE 403). URL, below is my code? Please help me.
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityConfig.class);

    // @Value("${spring.security.cas.server.login-url}")
    private String casLoginUrl = "http://192.168.203.50:8080/cas-server/login";

    // @Value("${spring.security.cas.server.logout-url}")
    private String casLogoutUrl = "http://192.168.203.50:8080/cas-server/logout";

    // @Value("${spring.security.cas.service.url}")
    private String casServiceUrl = "http://localhost:8080";

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    public SecurityConfig(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServiceProperties serviceProperties() {
        System.out.println("...............Configuring ServiceProperties with service URL: {}" + casServiceUrl);
        ServiceProperties serviceProperties = new ServiceProperties();
        serviceProperties.setService(casServiceUrl);
        serviceProperties.setSendRenew(false);
        serviceProperties.setAuthenticateAllArtifacts(true);
        logger.info("ServiceProperties configured with service URL: {}", casServiceUrl);
        return serviceProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    public TicketValidator ticketValidator() {
        System.out.println("...............Configuring TicketValidator with login URL: {}" + casLoginUrl);
        return new Cas20ServiceTicketValidator(casLoginUrl);
    }

    @Bean
    public CasAuthenticationProvider casAuthenticationProvider() {
        System.out.println("...............Configuring CasAuthenticationProvider");
        CasAuthenticationProvider provider = new CasAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setServiceProperties(serviceProperties());
        provider.setTicketValidator(ticketValidator());
        provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        provider.setKey("CAS_PROVIDER_LOCALHOST_9000");
        return provider;
    }

    @Bean
    public CasAuthenticationFilter casAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        System.out.println("...............Configuring CasAuthenticationFilter");
        CasAuthenticationFilter filter = new CasAuthenticationFilter();
        filter.setServiceProperties(serviceProperties());
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        return filter;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<SingleSignOutFilter> singleSignOutFilter() {
        System.out.println("...............Configuring SingleSignOutFilter");
        FilterRegistrationBean<SingleSignOutFilter> registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(
                new SingleSignOutFilter());
        registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");
        registrationBean.setName("CAS Single Sign Out Filter");
        registrationBean.setOrder(1);
        logger.info("SingleSignOutFilter registered");
        return registrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public LogoutFilter logoutFilter() {
        System.out.println("...............Configuring LogoutFilter");
        LogoutFilter filter = new LogoutFilter(casLogoutUrl, new SecurityContextLogoutHandler());
        filter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/logout");
        return filter;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("...............Configuring SecurityFilterChain");
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("/protected").hasAuthority("ROLE_USER") 
                        .anyRequest().permitAll() 
                )
                .logout((logout) -> logout
                        .logoutSuccessUrl("/"))
                .addFilterBefore(new CustomLoggingFilter(), CasAuthenticationFilter.class) 
                .addFilter(casAuthenticationFilter(http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManager.class)))
                .addFilterBefore(singleSignOutFilter().getFilter(), CasAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .addFilterBefore(logoutFilter(), LogoutFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<CustomLoggingFilter> loggingFilter() {
        FilterRegistrationBean<CustomLoggingFilter> registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
        registrationBean.setFilter(new CustomLoggingFilter());
        registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");
        registrationBean.setOrder(0); 
        return registrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("...............Configuring AuthenticationManager");
        return http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class)
                .authenticationProvider(casAuthenticationProvider())
                .build();
    }

    public static class CustomLoggingFilter implements Filter {
        private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomLoggingFilter.class);

        @Override
        public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        }

        @Override
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
                throws IOException, ServletException {
            logger.info("Request received at CustomLoggingFilter");
            System.out.println("request = " + ((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURL());
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
            logger.info("Response processed at CustomLoggingFilter"); 
        }

        @Override
        public void destroy() {
        }
    }

}

@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceConfig implements UserDetailsService {
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User
                .withUsername(username)
                .password("") 
                .authorities("ROLE_USER") 
                .build();
    }
}

I guess it's a problem with UserDetailsService, but I can't find the problem, please help me!!!
